# Checking User Roles in a model for use with an "if" statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

looking for a little help. I have a dashboard that populates a menu on the side according to roles. It uses the RoleId's to populate. This is done in a Class. I have found that I need to add a userId to the Dashboard link if certain roles are logged in. So I was hoping to use an `if` statement, However even though I have `using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;` the:

```
if (User.IsInRole("Admin")){ }
```

will not work. It says that `User` is undefined. I already have `http.Context` being used in the class, but I am unsure how to use what I have in an `if` statement. Currently I am returning a list of roles for the current user. Not sure how to pull that into an `if` statement.

Below is my code:

```
public static MvcHtmlString GetMenuBarPage(Guid? ParentId)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        GeneralEntities db = new GeneralEntities();
        var userId = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId();
        var userManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        List<string> roles = userManager.GetRoles(userId).ToList();
        IEnumerable<string> currentUserRoles = userManager.FindById(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId()).Roles.Select(r => r.RoleId);
        var cacheItemKey = "tylrwb" + userId + "Us" + currentUserRoles;

        var global = HttpRuntime.Cache.Get(cacheItemKey);
        if (global == null)
        {
            // Added IsForNavbar Pre-dates 02/09/2020
            global = db.MenuPermissions.Where(i => currentUserRoles.Contains(i.RoleId)
             && (i.UserId == userId || i.UserId == null) && i.IsForNavBar != false).ToArray();
            HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(cacheItemKey, global, null, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(2), System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
        }

       

        sb.Append("<ul class=\"sidebar-menu \"data-widget=\"tree\">");
        sb.Append("<li class=\"header\">MAIN NAVIGATION</li>");
        if (roles == "Admin")
        {
            sb.Append("<li> <a href=\"" + MicrosoftHelper.MSHelper.GetSiteRoot() + "/Dashboard\"> <i class=\"fa fa-line-chart\"></i> <span>Dashboard</span> </a> </li>");
            sb.Append("<li> <a href=\"" + MicrosoftHelper.MSHelper.GetSiteRoot() + "/Analytics\"> <i class=\"fa fa-line-chart\"></i> <span>Analytics</span> </a> </li>");
        }
        else
        {
            sb.Append("<li> <a href=\"" + MicrosoftHelper.MSHelper.GetSiteRoot() + "/Dashboard/" + HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId() + "\"> <i class=\"fa fa-dashboard\"></i> <span>Dashboard</span> </a> </li>");
        }
            
       
        sb.Append(GetMenuBar(ParentId, (MenuPermission[])global));
        sb.Append("</ul>");
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(sb.ToString());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I took a chance and put the code in a `foreach` to run through the list and it works. Sometimes I have my moments when my mind goes blank. Hope this helps others!

```
 public static MvcHtmlString GetMenuBarPage(Guid? ParentId)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        GeneralEntities db = new GeneralEntities();
        var userId = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId();
        var userManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        List<string> roles = userManager.GetRoles(userId).ToList();
        IEnumerable<string> currentUserRoles = userManager.FindById(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId()).Roles.Select(r => r.RoleId);
        var cacheItemKey = "tylrwb" + userId + "Us" + currentUserRoles;

        var global = HttpRuntime.Cache.Get(cacheItemKey);
        if (global == null)
        {
            // Added IsForNavbar Pre-dates 02/09/2020
            global = db.MenuPermissions.Where(i => currentUserRoles.Contains(i.RoleId)
             && (i.UserId == userId || i.UserId == null) && i.IsForNavBar != false).ToArray();
            HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(cacheItemKey, global, null, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(2), System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
        }

     

        sb.Append("<ul class=\"sidebar-menu \"data-widget=\"tree\">");
        sb.Append("<li class=\"header\">MAIN NAVIGATION</li>");
        foreach (var role in roles)
        {
            if (role == "Administrator")
            {
                sb.Append("<li> <a href=\"" + MicrosoftHelper.MSHelper.GetSiteRoot() + "/Dashboard\"> <i class=\"fa fa-line-chart\"></i> <span>Dashboard</span> </a> </li>");
                sb.Append("<li> <a href=\"" + MicrosoftHelper.MSHelper.GetSiteRoot() + "/Analytics\"> <i class=\"fa fa-line-chart\"></i> <span>Analytics</span> </a> </li>");
            }
            else
            {
                sb.Append("<li> <a href=\"" + MicrosoftHelper.MSHelper.GetSiteRoot() + "/Dashboard/" + HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId() + "\"> <i class=\"fa fa-dashboard\"></i> <span>Dashboard</span> </a> </li>");
            }
        }


        sb.Append(GetMenuBar(ParentId, (MenuPermission[])global));
        sb.Append("</ul>");
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(sb.ToString());
    }
```